# How do I get this while loop to dynamically produce this html?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a picture gallery, that uses this code to display each product I have:

```
<div class="feature">
            <a href="#"><imagetag alt="Image Caption"srcs=""></a>
            <div>
                <p>
                    This is some information that can go along with an image.
                    Anything can be placed here, including images.
                </p>
            </div>
</div>
```

I need to create a while loop, that takes all the products in my database, and creates a div of the "feature" class for every instance.  I have problems know exactly which symbols need to be escaped and etc.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

here is my start:

```
   <?php
 ($product_set = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  print("<div class="feature"> <a href="#"><imagetage alt="Image Caption" srcs=$product_set[products_image]></a>"


    );}
   ?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using something a little more semantic to contain the details? Given that it's a list, I'd suggest using a [`ul`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2), personally. Or, given that you appear to be showing something **and** explaining it, perhaps a [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/deflists.html).

Comment: @David the OP is a complete newb and you throw in 'semantic'???

Comment: @Yehonatan: Being new to StackOverflow doesn't mean you're a programming newb in all languages. ;)

Comment: @yehonatan: maybe s/he is; but why not *start* learning the 'right'(1) way, rather than having to re-learn later on? (1: it's, perhaps, no more 'right' this way than his own first attempt, but semantic html seems to convey more meaning about the content, so seems, at least, 'better,' if not objectively 'correct.')

Comment: @Marnix when i said newb - i meant he was a newb in programming not SO. you think sir skeet was a newb programmer when he had 10 reps here? dont think to hard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion DT, but i didn't actually write the code, so I don't want to have to change all the javascript, because I'm not that mean at.  I am new to programming, trying to learn as I go. But now I've just picked up so info on semantic html. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a string, every doublequote should be escaped. Because it will close your string.

```
<?php
    ($product_set = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {
        print "<div class=\"feature\"><a href=\"#\"><img alt=\"Image Caption\" src=" . $product_set['products_image'] . "></a>";
    }
?>
```

Fun thing is, I got a link from someone on stackOverflow about PHP templating. Which was using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). So you don't have to use these print states anymore.

Comment: Alternatively, they could use single quotes, exit from <?php ?> tags, use the heredoc syntax, or just review the php manpage on strings.

Comment: smarty looks cool. Is this library used a lot? is it well supported?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. But I use it on my web page now with just one single page and it works pretty well for printing. I was looking for the same problem, so that's why I implemented it, but I actually haven't checked any references.

Comment: Manrix.. do you do any freelance? I could use some help, and my current programmer has been to busy for my few needs.  hit me up: cue232s@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
    print(htmlentities($my_html_string))
or htmlspecialchars? htmlentities converts all characters that have one to their HTML escape sequence, while htmlspecialchars converts only those that have meaning in HTML.